# Optimize index on a 2,135,044,521 row table

Tags: sql-server, performance, index-tuning, azure-sql-database, query-performance

I have an I/O problem with a large table.

### General stats

The table has the following main characteristics:

- environment: Azure SQL Database (tier is P4 Premium (500 DTUs))
- rows: 2,135,044,521
- 1,275 used partitions
- clustered and partitioned index

### Model

This is the table implementation:

```
CREATE TABLE [data].[DemoUnitData](
    [UnitID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Value1] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Value2] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [Value3] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DemoUnitData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [UnitID] ASC,
        [Timestamp] ASC
    )
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [data].[DemoUnitData] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DemoUnitData_Unit] FOREIGN KEY([UnitID])
REFERENCES [model].[Unit] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [data].[DemoUnitData] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DemoUnitData_Unit]
GO
```

The partitioning is related to this:

```
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [DailyPartitionSchema] AS PARTITION [DailyPartitionFunction] ALL TO ([PRIMARY])

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [DailyPartitionFunction] (datetime) AS RANGE RIGHT
FOR VALUES (N'2017-07-25T00:00:00.000', N'2017-07-26T00:00:00.000', N'2017-07-27T00:00:00.000', ... )
```

### Quality of service

I think the indexes and statistics are well maintained every night by incremental rebuild/reorganize/update.

These are the current index stats of the most heavily used index partitions:

[image: Partition Stats]

These are the current statistics properties of the most heavily used partitions:

[image: Statistics]

#### Problem

I run a simple query on a high frequency against the table.

```
SELECT [UnitID]
    ,[Timestamp]
    ,[Value1]
    ,[Value2]
    ,[Value3]
FROM [data].[DemoUnitData]
WHERE [UnitID] = 8877 AND [Timestamp] >= '2018-03-01' AND [Timestamp] < '2018-03-13'
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

[image: exce count]

The execution plan looks like this: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJvI_4TtG

My problem is that these queries produce an extremely high amount of I/O operations resulting in a bottleneck of `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` waits.

[image: top waits]

### Question

I have read that `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` waits are often related to not well-optimized indexes. Are there any recommendations you have for me how to reduce I/O operations? Maybe by adding a better index?

---

### Answer 1 - related to comment from @S4V1N

The posted query plan was from a query I executed in SSMS. After your comment I do some research on the server history. The accual query exceuted from the service looks a bit different (EntityFramework related).

```
(@p__linq__0 bigint,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 datetime2(7)) 

SELECT 1 AS [C1], [Extent1] 
   .[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], [Extent1] 
   .[Value1] AS [Value1], [Extent1] 
   .[Value2] AS [Value2], [Extent1] 
   .[Value3] AS [Value3]  
FROM [data].[DemoUnitData] AS [Extent1]  
WHERE ([Extent1].[UnitID] = @p__linq__0)  
AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__1)  
AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] < @p__linq__2) OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Also, the plan looks different:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1fhALpKG

or

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1DFQvpKz

And like you can see here, our DB performance is hardly influenced by this query.

[image: Top SQL]

### Answer 2 - related to answer from @Joe Obbish

For testing the solution I replaced Entity Framework with a simple SqlCommand.
The result was an amazing performance boost!

The query plan is now the same as in SSMS and the logical reads and writes drop to ~8 per execution.

The overall I/O load drop to almost 0!
[image: I/O drop]

It also explains why I get a big performance drop after I changed the partition range from monthly to daily. The missing of partition elimination resulted in more partitions to scan.

Comment: Looking at the execution plan, that query does not seems that problematic at all.It has scanned only the necessary partitions with low amount of reads and it has not reported pageiolatch_sh waits (sos_sched..) instead. Which is understandable because you had no physical reads anyway. Are those cumulative waits, or taken over certain amount of time? Maybe problem is some other query after all.

Comment: I posted a detailed answer to you @S4V1N above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be able to reduce `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` waits for this query if you're able to change the data types generated by the ORM. The `Timestamp` column in your table has a data type of `DATETIME` but the parameters `@p__linq__1` and `@p__linq__2` have data types of `DATETIME2(7)`. That difference is why the query plan for the ORM queries is so much more complicated than the first query plan that you posted that had hardcoded search filters. You can get a hint of this in the XML as well:

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="GetRangeWithMismatchedTypes([@p__linq__1],NULL,(22))">
```

As is, with the ORM query you cannot get any partition elimination. You will get at least a few logical reads for every partition that's defined in the partition function, even if you're just searching for a day of data. Within each partition you get an index seek so it doesn't take long for SQL Server to move on to the next partition, but perhaps all of that IO is adding up.

I did a simple reproduction to be sure. There are 11 partitions defined within the partition function. For this query:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 bigint = 2000;
DECLARE @p__linq__1 datetime2(7) = '20180103';
DECLARE @p__linq__2 datetime2(7) = '20180104';

SELECT 1 AS [C1]
, [Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp]
, [Extent1].[Value1] AS [Value1]
FROM [DemoUnitData] AS [Extent1]  
WHERE ([Extent1].[UnitID] = @p__linq__0)  
AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__1)  
AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] < @p__linq__2)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1) ;
```

Here's what IO looks like:

> Table 'DemoUnitData'. Scan count 11, logical reads 40

When I fix the data types:

```
DECLARE @p__linq__0 bigint = 2000;
DECLARE @p__linq__1 datetime = '20180103';
DECLARE @p__linq__2 datetime = '20180104';

SELECT 1 AS [C1]
, [Extent1].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp]
, [Extent1].[Value1] AS [Value1]
FROM [DemoUnitData] AS [Extent1]  
WHERE ([Extent1].[UnitID] = @p__linq__0)  
AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] >= @p__linq__1)  
AND ([Extent1].[Timestamp] < @p__linq__2)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1) ;
```

IO is reduced as a result of partition elimination:

> Table 'DemoUnitData'. Scan count 2, logical reads 8